# UTF-8 file BULK INSERT with broken pipe field returns error

Tags: sql-server, utf-8, bulkinsert, sql-server-2016

I'm trying to load an UTF-8 flat file with a broken pipe (¦) delimiter.

The content of the flat file is very simple and the line is ended by CRLF

```
AAA¦BBB¦CCC
```

The code is

```
create table l_testfile
(COL1 nvarchar(255),
COL2 nvarchar(255),
COL3 nvarchar(255)
)


BULK INSERT l_testfile
FROM 'C:\testfile.txt'
WITH (CODEPAGE = '65001', DATAFILETYPE = 'Char', FIELDTERMINATOR = '¦')
```

And this results in the error

> Msg 4832, Level 16, State 1, Line 16 Bulk load: An unexpected end of
>   file was encountered in the data file. Msg 7399, Level 16, State 1,
>   Line 16 The OLE DB provider "BULK" for linked server "(null)" reported
>   an error. The provider did not give any information about the error.
>   Msg 7330, Level 16, State 2, Line 16 Cannot fetch a row from OLE DB
>   provider "BULK" for linked server "(null)".

When changing the broken pipe (¦) to a normal pipe (|), the BULK INSERT works ok. Also loading an ANSI file with a broken pipe is not giving any error.

Am I missing something ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't have access to a SQL 2016 instance I can test this on right now, but I believe the issue is caused by the different ways the `¦` character is encoded between UTF-8 and your local `varchar` codepage.

When you specify `FIELDTERMINATOR` in the `BULK INSERT` command, you're specifying it as a `varchar` - but the [encoding of `¦`](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/00A6/index.htm) in most single-byte codepages is `0xA6`, whereas in UTF-8 it's `0xC2A6` - as a result, the terminator is never matched, which causes the error (I'm not certain but I suspect this is because the single-byte value is converted internally to the UCS2-LE representation `0x00A6`).

I believe the bulk insert should work correctly if you use the the bytes which make up `¦` in UTF-8 as the `FIELDTERMINATOR`:

```
BULK INSERT l_testfile
FROM 'C:\testfile.txt'
WITH (CODEPAGE = '65001', DATAFILETYPE = 'Char', FIELDTERMINATOR = '0xC2A6')
```

(Using `|` as a delimiter is successful because it's encoded

Comment: Hello, thank you for the reply.

Specifying `FIELDTERMINATOR = '0xC2A6'` is also generating the same error.

When the codepage is not specified, the correct data is inserted. This seems strange to me ? `BULK INSERT l_testfile
FROM 'C:\testfile.txt'
WITH (DATAFILETYPE = 'Char', FIELDTERMINATOR = '0xC2A6')`